# How to select from joined table with WHERE clause only when value exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

I want to SELECT one record from table1 (WHERE t1.id = 1) and then JOIN table2 and table3 (t2.field2 and t3.field3) to table1 but ONLY if the values exists (IS NOT NULL).

So for example, if the value doesn't exist for t3.field3, the field3 column is not displayed for that table...

```
   t1

 id  |  field1
---------------
 1   |   f1val
 2   |   f1val
 3   |   f1val


       t2

 id(fk)  |  field2
-------------------
 1       |   f2val
 2       |   null
 3       |   null


       t3

 id(fk)  |  field3
-------------------
 1       |   null
 2       |   f3val
 3       |   f3val
```

the code I tried to do is this:

```
    SELECT t1.id, t2.field1, t3.field3
    FROM (
       SELECT t1.id
       FROM t1
       WHERE t1.id = 1
    )
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.id is not null
   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t3.id is not null;
```

The joined table returned from the query above looks like this:

```
 id  |  field2  | field3
----------------------------
  1  |   f1val  |  null
```

However, since field3 is null, I want it to return only the id and field2 like this:

```
  id  |  field2  
----------------
   1  |  f1val
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: You can add another `WHERE` clause either on the joined tables, or when joining with t3 (select only fields for which value is not null).

Comment: You can't return two or three columns based on WHERE. But based on your example data you might want `coalesce(t2.field1, t3.field3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* return one column, using `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t2.field1, t3.field3) as field_2_3
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2 
     ON t2.id = t1.id LEFT JOIN
     t3
     ON t3.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

However, you cannot sometimes return two columns and sometimes return 3 columns.

Notes:

- The subquery on `t1` is utterly unnecessary.  You can just apply the filter in a single `WHERE` clause.
- The comparisons for `IS NOT NULL` are unnecessary because they fail the `JOIN` condition anyway.
- The last `JOIN` condition is presumably on `t3.id = t1.id`.